# editing text in a file using racket

Tags: text, racket, editing

I have a racket program that (include file)'s several other files some of which contain racket code that I want to update using functions in the main program. I.e. This is what the file I want to edit looks like (basically)

```
(define somethings '(
        (some list)
        (some other list)
        (yet another list)))
```

I would like to be able to add more things to the list I presume there's a better way to do this but since I'm new to this is what I tried first:

```
(define (update-file arg1 arg2 arg3 . args)
    (call-with-output-file "somefile.rkt" #:exists 'append
       (lambda (output-port)
          (print "\b\b" output-port) ;; have tried several variations of this they all 
          (do other things)          ;; print the backspaces literally rather than 
          (display "))" output-port) ;; removing characters
          (newline output-port))))
```

I presume the problem is both A: I'm using append which presumably just sticks stuff on the end (but update and truncate don't seem like the answer) and B: printing \b doesn't work the way I'm trying to use it... :)

I'm hopelessly browsing through racket's documentation now, but I'm new to programming so a large part of it doesn't make any sense yet. Is there some way of making that particular function work and if so would it be worth it or is there a far superior method to achieve the same result?

Thanks very much

Comment: The best way to edit an S-expression programmatically is to treat it as a data structure (by `read`ing it in), updating it, then writing it back out (using `write`), rather than treating it as a string of text.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Ah, thanks much better idea. I'm not sure precisely how to implement that but I'll figure that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(call-with-input-file "somefile.rkt"
  (lambda (in)
    (let* ((input  (call-with-input-string (port->string in) read))
           (output (list (car input)  ; define
                         (cadr input) ; somethings
                         (list 'quote
                               (append
                                (car (cdaddr input))      ; old list
                                '((do other things))))))) ; new elements
      (call-with-output-file "somefile.rkt" #:exists 'replace
        (lambda (out)
          (write output out))))))
```

This is what's happening:

1. First, we `read` the contents of `"somefile.rkt"` into a variable called `input`, the result is a list of S-Expressions
2. Then, as suggested by Chris, we manipulate that list using standard operations until it has the desired value
3. Finally, we `write` the result back into the same file, overwriting the previous contents

At the end, `"somefile.rkt"` will contain the following text:

```
(define somethings
  (quote
   ((some list)
    (some other list)
    (yet another list)
    (do other things))))
```

Don't worry about the `quote`, that's the same as writing `'`. The only caveat is that the original format of the text will be lost, everything shows in a single line.

Comment: Oscar Lopez Thanks, that works. I solved the problem differently (because I didn't know how to deal with the define) and defined a variable in the main file as `(read file-in)` (file-in being: `(define file-in (open-input-file file.rkt)`), and just having the file.txt contain a quoted list. I'm not sure which solution is more flexible but I can pretty-print mine so it's readable. I presume that possible with yours with some modification. What's the benefit of using `'replace` instead of `'truncate` with `(call-with-out-put-file)` ?

Comment: @user138888 ok! what matters is that you understand how the solution works, no matter which one you pick :) There's no particular "benefit" of using `'replace` or `'truncate`, they just do different things, see the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._open-output-file%29%29) for the explanation of each flag